# Separation of time scales to solve ODEs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, oscillators

I am reading several papers that obtain approximate solutions to nonlinear ODEs using a "standard technique" to separate the time scales of the dynamics.

For examples, consider the ODE (a particle in double well potential):
$$\dot{x} -x +x^3 =F\cos{\omega t} +G\cos{\Omega t}$$ where $\Omega \gg \omega$.
Assume a solution of the form $$x= X(t,\omega t) + \Psi(t,\Omega t)$$ where $X$ and $\Psi$ are the slow and fast motion components with periods $\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{\Omega}$ respectively. 
Then by averaging over the fast time scale they obtain:
$$
\dot{X} -X +X^3 +3X\langle{\Psi^2}\rangle + 3X^2\langle\Psi\rangle = F\cos{\omega t}\\
\dot{\Psi} -\Psi +\Psi^3 +3X(\Psi^2 - \langle{\Psi^2}\rangle) + 3X^2(\Psi-\langle\Psi\rangle) = G\cos{\Omega t}
$$
where $$\langle\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \Psi d\tau , \tau=\Omega t.$$

My question is how to actually obtain the last 2 equations. 
I tried to just plug in the ansatz and integrate over $\tau$ but I don't see how to get to 2 separate equations.

Comment: Which papers? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Ex1: PHYSICAL REVIEW E 67, 066119 (2003) page 2. Ex2: PHYSICAL REVIEW E 83, 066205 (2011) page 2. Ex3: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5394v1.pdf page 6-7. There are more but they all do the same thing without giving out details. And this is not homework.